# Lumen 5.0 Request Object Parameters Empty When Using CrawlerTrait::call()

Tags: testing, laravel-5, phpunit, lumen-5.2

When testing an API Endpoint with a call to CrawlerTrait::call() from a PHPUnit test.

```
$this->call(
    'GET',
     'api/v3/user?page[size]=20'
);
```

or

```
$this->call(
    'GET',
     'api/v3/user,
     [ 'page' => [ 'size' => 20 ] ]
);
```

With a route:

```
$app->group(['prefix'=>'api/v3','namespace'=>'MyAPI\V3core\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    /* User */
    $app->get('user', ['as' => 'user.read', 'uses' => 'UserController@read');
});
```

With a controller:

```
public function read(Request $request, $id = false)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

The contents of **$request** passed to the controller has an empty $request->request->parameters:

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {
    #parameters: []
}
```

Whereas when I request the same API endpoint via a Browser, Postman or even wget the request Object is returned with a populated **$request->request->parameters**.

```
+request: ParameterBag {
    #parameters: array:1 [
        "page" => array:1 [
        "size" => "20"
    ]
  ]
}
```

This causes pagination or any query driven functionality to be untestable, as it works in the browser but not via the CrawlerTrait::call();

It's worth mentioning that the returned Response when using CrawlerTrait::call() has the query attribute set instead of the parameters attribute.

```
+query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {
    #parameters: array:1 [
        "page" => array:1 [
        "size" => 20
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm also seeing this irregularity. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No unfortunately not, I decided to use Guzzle instead.

Comment: In Laravel 5.1 I was able to fix this by replacing references of $_GET within my application with \Input::get()

Comment: I am having similar kind a problem too. In my case i am getting empty request in browser as well.   If i do dd($request); i get empty parameters and if i do dd($_POST) i do get param value properly.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/416 may hold a work around, I however have not.